# MAUI - Binding ObservableCOllection<string> to ListView Throws System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Adding a `ListView` to my page is throwing a runtime exception when I try and navigate to the page using `Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CollectionItemDetails(item));`  I'm wondering if I've malformed my XAML somehow or if my Binding is off, as removing the listview prevents the exception from happening.

**The Listview XAML See ListView at the bottom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CollectionItemDetails"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespaceViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Item.Name}">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:CollectionItemDetailsViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>

        <!--Header Display-->
        <FlexLayout HorizontalOptions="{OnPlatform WinUI=Start, Default=Center}"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                    Wrap="Wrap">

            <!--Image-->
            <Frame CornerRadius="45"
                   HeightRequest="300"
                   WidthRequest="300"
                   HasShadow="False">
                <Image Source="{Binding Item.Image}"
                       HeightRequest="300"
                       MinimumWidthRequest="300"
                       Margin="-20"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            </Frame>

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="{OnPlatform WinUI=StartAndExpand, Default=Center}">
                <Label Text="{Binding Item.Name}"
                       FontSize="{OnPlatform WinUI=Header, Default=Title}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>               
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="50"
                      HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!--PlayerCount-->
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="0"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center"  FontSize="Small">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding Item.MinPlayers}"/>
                                    <Span Text="-"/>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding Item.MaxPlayers}"/>
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                        <Image x:Name="PlayerCountIMG" 
                               Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=players.png, Dark=playerswhite.png}" 
                               HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>

                    <!--Playtime-->
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" Text="{Binding Item.PlayTime}"/>
                        <Image Source="clock.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>

                    <!--Age-->
                    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="2" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding Item.MinAge}"/>
                                    <Span Text="+"/>
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                        <Image Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=age.png, Dark=agewhite.png}" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>

                    <Label Grid.Column="3"
                           VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="Weight: " 
                                      FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Span Text="{Binding Item.Statistics.Ratings.AverageWeights.Value, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                                      TextColor="Orange"
                                      FontAttributes="Bold"/>                                
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                </Grid>
                
                <!--Publishers  This is causing the breakage-->
                <ListView BindingContext="{Binding Publishers}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding}"/>                       
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <!--<ListView BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Item.Publishers}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>-->
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexLayout>

        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}"
               TextType="Html"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class CollectionItemDetails : ContentPage
{
    public ICollectionItemDetailsViewModel itemViewModel;

    public CollectionItemDetails(CollectionPageItem item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init(item);
    }

    private void Init(CollectionPageItem item)
    {
        itemViewModel = BootStrapper.Resolve<ICollectionItemDetailsViewModel>(new[] { new NamedParameter("item", item) });
        BindingContext = itemViewModel;
    }
}
```

**The ViewModel**

```
public class CollectionItemDetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICollectionItemDetailsViewModel
    {
        public CollectionItemDetailsViewModel()
        {
        }

        public CollectionItemDetailsViewModel(CollectionPageItem item)
        {
            Item = item;
            Publishers = Item.Publishers.ToObservableCollection();
        }
    
        public CollectionPageItem Item { get; private set; }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _publishers = new();

        public ObservableCollection<string> Publishers
        { 
            get => _publishers;
            private set { _publishers = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Publishers)); }
        }
    }
```

I originally tried to Bind the `ListView` to the Item.Publishers property, which is an `IList<string>`, but because of the exception I tried to expose the property as an `ObservableCollection<string>` even though this page does will not actually need to be watching for changes.  Unfortunately still getting the exception.

**Exception Details**

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x88000FA8
  Message=0x88000FA8
  Source=WinRT.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.INavigationView2.global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.INavigationView2.set_PaneDisplayMode(NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode value)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView.set_PaneDisplayMode(NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellItemHandler.MapTabBarIsVisible(ShellItemHandler handler, ShellItem item)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.SendNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.<.ctor>b__169_0(Object _, ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<HandleNavigated>g__FireNavigatedEvents|1(ShellNavigatedEventArgs a, Shell shell)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<HandleNavigated>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page.OnAppearing(Action action)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BaseShellItem.OnAppearing(Action action)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.HandleNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.<GoToAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.NavigationImpl.<OnPushModal>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shell.NavigationImpl.<OnPushModal>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ..\.CollectionViewModel.<ItemTapped>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\ViewModels\CollectionViewModel.cs:line 114
```

Comment: A possible work around is replacing the `ListView` with a `Label` and setting the text in the code behind using something like `string.join()`, but this has a a code smell and I'd prefer to get the listview working if possible